# Add all items with git add but images

Tags: git

Good afternoon. I am currently working on a project and I have been asked to do git add on all items in order to commit them and push them to a bitbucket repo. However, they have asked me to not commit any images (png or jpg). So my question is, how can I do git add without adding the images? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the .gitignore file to make git ignore images.

This could be as simple as creating a file called ".gitignore" (note that it starts with a period) that contains these lines:

```
*.jpg
*.png
```

Alternatively, you could reset them prior to creating your commit:

```
git add .
git reset -- \*.png
git reset -- \*.jpg
git commit -m "my commit!"
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to use git add and then do git reset for all .jpg or .png files? I am currently working on a putty server and i have already ran a large model, so uploading a gitignore from my computer and doing git pull from putty now is not the best idea. The .jpg and .png files are inside folders.

Comment: I added a quick example of how to reset the staging of your images prior to creating your commit :)